# Ionic router - Non-linear routing

Tags: ionic-framework, vue-router

I'm writing Vue3 + Ionic app for Android, and I have a few tabs. I want to maintain a different navigation stack for each tab, so when users click the back button on some view they will always stay on the current tab.
This is the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/navigation#non-linear-routing
I didn't manage to achieve this.

This is my router:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from '@ionic/vue-router'
import type { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
import AppTabs from '@/components/AppTabs.vue'
import RecipeView from '@/views/RecipeView/RecipeView.vue'

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/tabs/home'
  },
  {
    path: '/tabs/',
    component: AppTabs,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirect: '/tabs/home'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: () => import('@/layout/HomeTab.vue'),
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: () => import('@/views/HomeView.vue'),
          },
          {
            path: 'recipes',
            component: () => import('@/views/RecipesView.vue')
          },
          {
            path: 'recipe/:id?',
            component: RecipeView
          },
          {
            path: 'categories',
            component: () => import('@/views/CategoriesView.vue')
          },
          {
            path: 'addRecipeStep1',
            component: () => import('@/views/AddRecipe/AddRecipeStep1.vue')
          },
          {
            path: 'addRecipeStep2',
            component: () => import('@/views/AddRecipe/AddRecipeStep2/AddRecipeStep2.vue')
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'collections',
        component: () => import('@/layout/CollectionTab.vue'),
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: () => import('@/views/CollectionsView.vue'),
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'groceries',
        component: () => import('@/views/GroceriesView.vue')
      },
      {
        path: 'settings',
        component: () => import('@/views/SettingsView.vue')
      }
    ]
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

tabs component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  IonTabBar,
  IonTabButton,
  IonTabs,
  IonLabel,
  IonIcon,
  IonPage,
  IonRouterOutlet,
} from '@ionic/vue'
import { clipboardOutline, settingsOutline, restaurantOutline, bookmarkOutline } from 'ionicons/icons'

</script>

<template>
  <IonPage>
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
      <IonTabBar slot="bottom" class="tab-bar">
        <ion-tab-button tab="home" href="/tabs/home">
          <IonIcon :icon="restaurantOutline" />
          <IonLabel>Home</IonLabel>
        </ion-tab-button>


        <ion-tab-button tab="collections" href="/tabs/collections">
          <IonIcon :icon="bookmarkOutline" />
          <IonLabel>Collections</IonLabel>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="groceries" href="/tabs/groceries">
          <IonIcon :icon="clipboardOutline" />
          <IonLabel>Groceries</IonLabel>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="settings" href="/tabs/settings">
          <IonIcon :icon="settingsOutline" />
          <IonLabel>Settings</IonLabel>
        </ion-tab-button>
      </IonTabBar>
    </ion-tabs>
  </IonPage>
</template>
```

and this is home-tab:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { IonPage, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/vue';
</script>

<template>
    <IonPage>
        <div class="home-tab">
            <IonRouterOutlet />
        </div>
    </IonPage>
</template>
```

I tried to have different `IonRouterOutlet` in each tab, but still this flow doesn't work:

1. I go to some nested route in the Home tab
2. Switch to Collection tab
3. Go back to Home tab
4. I do see the last page I visited in the Home tab, but clicking 'back' (`ionRouter.back()`) it takes me to the Collection tab, not the previous Home tab stack.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution thanks to this issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/25213
Using `ion-back-button` works.